# Writing into files with editing from a texbox in C#

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter

The problem is that whatever I write into the textbox and save it into the file, it shows as one big line. The enters do not get recorded. This is the code that saves the file to the file.

```
 StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Hpath);
 sw.Write(richTextBox1.Text);
 sw.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a rich text box control, you can just use the savefile method:

```
richTextBox1.SaveFile(Hpath, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

This appeared to work as I entered multiple lines in using the "enter" key for line breaks.

Comment: Its the host file. Its type is file

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the .[Lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx) property. Then you can write each line to your file.

Comment: the textbox opens a file(which has many lines). how will I enter the lines in the .Lines property for that, since it is an array.